# Set a global var in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

How can I set a variable in maven project in jenkins and use it across all non dependent jobs. This variable is not static and I can only set it via executing a job based on some conditions

Comment: I might not have understood the correct scenario, but if some jobs require a variable value which is generated by another job, say jobA, aren't those job dependent on jobA ?

Comment: actaully this is a global variable which is set on the basis of result of job A and need to be used across multiple jobs not one. we need to export a var from job to jenkins environment

Answer (score 0):

You can set global variable programmatically through custom script.
Though I haven't tried/tested this personally, you can custom script on this google groups discussion.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/KgCGuDmED1Q

Note what it says :

> That code is a global configuration script which needs to be executed
>   from the "Groovy console" of the Jenkins server.
>
> It can't be used from a Jenkinsfile.

So, you might have to execute it outside the job. Once done, you can consume the global variable in downstream job(s).